# Back4App deploying folder with .js file issue

Tags: parse-cloud-code, back4app

I just deployed main.js file and all works good. But then I tried to create folder and added a file to it.

After that deployment alert says that something went wrong.

[image]

[image]

Do I need to put this folder to public directory or actually what is the purpose of this two folders cloud and public?

Looks like it is simple because the file delete_project_employee_rules.js does not have any code lines.

Comment: In this case, I recommend you to check it with the Back4App Team. You can talk to their support or open a ticket here: https://www.back4app.com/support, then, they will check why you're facing this issue with the deploy

Comment: thank you @Charles. I will and looks like it is pretty clear issue when file does not contain any source code text. It makes no sense to upload such file. but I accidentally did not save a file locally. Probably changing alert text is enough. But I have realised the issue very quick.